# hwpf, xwpf, hssf, and xslf poi picture extraction

Tags: image, performance, class, apache-poi, extract

I'm looking to extract all images from new and legacy Word documents and spreadsheets to assist in a real time document classification system, and looking at the documentation, I seem to have run into a problem. I'm having no problems finding documentation within the hwpf module and packages for extracting images from the file, but when it comes to the other 3, it seems as though they don't support the same methods.

What I want to do is to have one block of code that is document type agnostic when it comes to the 4 above mentioned types, I just want fast, easy access to the pictures in the files so I can move on to my next task, but at this point it looks like only the hwpf module supports extraction of pictures or the methods in 'PicturesTable'.

I'm also somewhat concerned about the performance of the library: it looks like it loads the entire file when all I want to do is scrape the images out of it. Any suggestions on a library that operates directly on the 'Data' bytestream and the folder structure of the `.***x` zip files?

I've already tried using OLEtools to try to extract pictures from the streams, and I'm now moving on to this tool. I havn't tried any tools that operate on the lower levels of the documents yet though.

Comment: There are some libs that support streaming when reading .***x files but they only cover some formats and tend to not to focus on images (focusing on the text content). The .***x files are basically zip files (if the files are not password protected). Try unzipping your file and finding the images. You might be able to build your own code based on what you discover.

Comment: The issue is with the legacy formats. You can still unzip those, but the media is all stored in a "Data" bytestream whose datastructure I don't understand.